# How to change stroke color of a drawable with Kotlin or Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable

I have a drawable object that I use to set the background of a linear layout, leaving the linear with the circular shape with a semi transparent orange line. but at some point in the code I need to change the color of this background (drawable object) to a color that I have only as a parameter and I don't have it in the colors of my color file. I need to change the stroke color of this drawable to a color that I have in one of my runtime variables

bg_static_show_password.xml

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <!-- center circle -->
    <stroke android:color="@color/accent_color_alpha"
            android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <size
        android:width="28dp"
        android:height="28dp"/>
</shape>
```

linear layout

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/card_show_password"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/anim_layout_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/anim_layout_size"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/anim_margin_top"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_static_show_password"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_group_item"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
```

method I'm trying to use to make this color change

```
fun showAlternativeForAnimation(view: LinearLayout) {
        val drawable = view.background as GradientDrawable
        val theme = PasswordRecoveryTheme(ApplicationSession.instance?.themeId)
        drawable.setStroke(1, theme.getAccentColor(ApplicationFactory.context!!))

    }
```

the parameter of method is the LinearLayout

When I try, I get this exception:
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Comment: You said you're trying to change the background of a *LinearLayout* but you're actually using a *ConstraintLayout*. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: Actually the constraint layout and the parent view, inside it I have this linearlayout with the background I want to change, in this case the constraint is not important because it can be any layout, the fact in this case is that the linear layout is inside another layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a safe cast (`as?`), ensure that the view you pass has a shape drawable set as it's background and change parameter to `view: View` so as to allow usage for any view(LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc).

```
fun showAlternativeForAnimation(view: View) {
    val drawable = view.background as? GradientDrawable
    val theme = PasswordRecoveryTheme(ApplicationSession.instance?.themeId)
    drawable?.setStroke(1, theme.getAccentColor(ApplicationFactory.context!!))
}
```

Comment: thanks Chrisvin, but in this case only my problem of changing the color of this drawable has not been solved, it is just avoiding nullPointerException

Comment: It's giving you a null because you're probably passing the layout (that doesn't have a shape drawable as it's background) as the argument.

Comment: Really, I was going wrong layout, thank you so much for opening my eyes kkkk